# Submit a Form using AJAX in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.2

I am working with ASP.Net Core 2.2, and trying submit a contact form while returning a message de: "success" or "error", without refreshing the page.
the form works, but I would like to submit with ajax, I'm trying with this

My code looks like :

I'm loading these script

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery.validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

additionally I have this function

```js
(function($) {
$('.contact-form').each(function(){
  $(this).validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {

    var $form = $(form),
     $messageSuccess = $form.find('.contact-form-success'),
     $messageError = $form.find('.contact-form-error'),
     $submitButton = $(this.submitButton),
     $errorMessage = $form.find('.mail-error-message'),
     submitButtonText = $submitButton.val();

    $submitButton.val( $submitButton.data('loading-text') ? $submitButton.data('loading-text') : 'Loading...' ).attr('disabled', true);

    // Fields Data
    var formData = $form.serializeArray(),
     data = {};

    $(formData).each(function(index, obj){
        data[obj.name] = obj.value;
    });

    // Google Recaptcha
    if( data["g-recaptcha-response"] != undefined ) {
     data["g-recaptcha-response"] = $form.find('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
    }

    // Ajax Submit
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: $form.attr('action'),
     data: data
    }).always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

     $errorMessage.empty().hide();

     if (data.response == 'success') {

      // Uncomment the code below to redirect for a thank you page
      // self.location = 'thank-you.html';

      $messageSuccess.removeClass('d-none');
      $messageError.addClass('d-none');

      // Reset Form
      $form.find('.form-control')
       .val('')
       .blur()
       .parent()
       .removeClass('has-success')
       .removeClass('has-danger')
       .find('label.error')
       .remove();

      if (($messageSuccess.offset().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()) {
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $messageSuccess.offset().top - 80
       }, 300);
      }

      $form.find('.form-control').removeClass('error');

      $submitButton.val( submitButtonText ).attr('disabled', false);
      
      return;

     } else if (data.response == 'error' && typeof data.errorMessage !== 'undefined') {
      $errorMessage.html(data.errorMessage).show();
     } else {
      $errorMessage.html(data.responseText).show();
     }

     $messageError.removeClass('d-none');
     $messageSuccess.addClass('d-none');

     if (($messageError.offset().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $messageError.offset().top - 80
      }, 300);
     }

     $form.find('.has-success')
      .removeClass('has-success');
      
     $submitButton.val( submitButtonText ).attr('disabled', false);

    });
   }
  });
 });
  }).apply(this, [jQuery]);
```

My HTML

```html
<form method="post" id="contactForm" class="contact-form form-style-4 form-errors-light custom-form-style-1">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-lg-12 ml-auto my-0">
                                    <div class="contact-form-success alert alert-success d-none" id="contactSuccess">
                                        Message has been sent to us.
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="contact-form-error alert alert-danger d-none" id="contactError">
                                        Error sending your message.
                                        <span class="mail-error-message text-1 d-block" id="mailErrorMessage"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                        <input asp-for="Contacts.Name" data-msg-required="¡Por favor ingrese su nombre!" class="form-control py-2" placeholder="Nombre completo" required />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Contacts.Name" class="error"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                        <input asp-for="Contacts.Phone" data-msg-required="¡El número de teléfono es requerido!" class="form-control py-2" placeholder="Teléfono" required />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Contacts.Phone" class="error"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col">
                                        <input asp-for="Contacts.Email" data-msg-required="¡Su e-mail es requerido!" class="form-control py-2" placeholder="E-mail" required />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Contacts.Email" class="error"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col">
                                        <textarea asp-for="Contacts.Message" data-msg-required="¡El mensaje no puede ir en blanco!" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="Contacts.Message" class="error"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="custom-btn-style-1 btn btn-dark font-weight-bold text-uppercase btn-px-5 py-3">
                            </form>
```

My Action Controller

```html
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            var tempMenssage = "Hola Cecilia! <br/> Nos alegra informarte que que tienes un mensaje nuevo, acontinuación tu mensaje. <br/> <b>Nombre de la persona que te contácta: </b>" + Contacts.Name + "<br/><b>Su e-mail es el siguiente:</b> " + Contacts.Email + "<br/><b>A continuación el mensaje:</b> " + Contacts.Message;

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                    "mi-email@gmail.com",
                    "Tiene un nuevo mensaje",
                    tempMenssage);

            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
```